# How to use patool in a pyinstaller .exe

Tags: pyinstaller, ipatool

I have a simple python script that unpack a file.rar It works fine until I compile it into an exe with pyinstaller and it stops working.

> Python 3.7    Windows 7  PyInstaller 3.4

My file.py

```
   from pyunpack import Archive
   import os
   import os.path as path
   import subprocess

   path=os.getcwd()
   Archive('MyFile.rar').extractall(path)
```

I tried to place myself in:

Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks

and add hook called "hook-patoolib.py" with the following content

[hook-patoolib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvvZT.jpg)

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2013-2017, PyInstaller Development Team.
#
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License with exception
# for distributing bootloader.
#
# The full license is in the file COPYING.txt, distributed with this software.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


"""
patoolib uses importlib and pyinstaller doesn't find it and add it to the list of needed modules
"""


hiddenimports = [
    'patoolib.programs',
    'patoolib.programs.ar',
    'patoolib.programs.arc',
    'patoolib.programs.archmage',
    'patoolib.programs.bsdcpio',
    'patoolib.programs.bsdtar',
    'patoolib.programs.bzip2',
    'patoolib.programs.cabextract',
    'patoolib.programs.chmlib',
    'patoolib.programs.clzip',
    'patoolib.programs.compress',
    'patoolib.programs.cpio',
    'patoolib.programs.dpkg',
    'patoolib.programs.flac',
    'patoolib.programs.genisoimage',
    'patoolib.programs.gzip',
    'patoolib.programs.isoinfo',
    'patoolib.programs.lbzip2',
    'patoolib.programs.lcab',
    'patoolib.programs.lha',
    'patoolib.programs.lhasa',
    'patoolib.programs.lrzip',
    'patoolib.programs.lzip',
    'patoolib.programs.lzma',
    'patoolib.programs.lzop',
    'patoolib.programs.mac',
    'patoolib.programs.nomarch',
    'patoolib.programs.p7azip',
    'patoolib.programs.p7rzip',
    'patoolib.programs.p7zip',
    'patoolib.programs.pbzip2',
    'patoolib.programs.pdlzip',
    'patoolib.programs.pigz',
    'patoolib.programs.plzip',
    'patoolib.programs.py_bz2',
    'patoolib.programs.py_echo',
    'patoolib.programs.py_gzip',
    'patoolib.programs.py_lzma',
    'patoolib.programs.py_tarfile',
    'patoolib.programs.py_zipfile',
    'patoolib.programs.rar',
    'patoolib.programs.rpm',
    'patoolib.programs.rpm2cpio',
    'patoolib.programs.rzip',
    'patoolib.programs.shar',
    'patoolib.programs.shorten',
    'patoolib.programs.star',
    'patoolib.programs.tar',
    'patoolib.programs.unace',
    'patoolib.programs.unadf',
    'patoolib.programs.unalz',
    'patoolib.programs.uncompress',
    'patoolib.programs.unrar',
    'patoolib.programs.unshar',
    'patoolib.programs.unzip',
    'patoolib.programs.xdms',
    'patoolib.programs.xz',
    'patoolib.programs.zip',
    'patoolib.programs.zoo',
    'patoolib.programs.zopfli',
    'patoolib.programs.zpaq',
]
```

but I'm still getting

> patool can not unpack

Comment: In case you have found a solution, I would be very interested to know about it

Comment: I opened a neighbouring question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60655910/use-pyunpack-inside-an-executable-file-made-with-pyinstaller-in-combination-with